# Connecting ADO.Net Entity Data Model Wizard to MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am following [this guide at dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html) to use an Entity Framework Entity.

I have got to point 3 but my data connection is not showing in the data connection drop down box.

[image]

I originally made a new (working) connection using [this guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-visual-studio-making-a-connection.html), this connection is displayed in the Server Explorer panel and I can see the tables etc. How can I make the connection appear in the dropdown list in the Entity Data Model List?

Comment: Down voters leave no comment?

Comment: Click on the button "New connection..." and configure it, on top of my head I think it would be shown in the drop down the second/third/fourth... time(s) you open this wizard

Comment: @snajahi I have a connection in Server Explorer but the Entity Data Model Wizard shows no connection. When I create a new connection MySQL is not shown in the list of data sources whereas it did when I created the connection in Server Explorer.

Comment: @tallpaul, I have been downvoted without an explanation also. Someone else said it might be because we are supposed to provide version information and other such information. I agree there should be an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who has this problem. Rebuild the solution after adding the connection in Server Explorer and the option appears in the drop down list.

Comment: I think I have the problem too. The connection existed and works in Server Explorer before creating the solution but the Entity Data Model Wizard shows no connection.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  Also, when I click "New connection" I don't have "MySQL Database" as an option  (although it is an option in Server Explorer)